# How to call Java method from h:outputlink and pass value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this output `h:outputLink' to open a new page and pass a value:

```
<h:outputLink id="link" value="newpage.jsf"  style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.value}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I need to add Java method which is called after I click the link. I saw that `h:outputLink` don't have action listener which I can use for calling Java method. I tested to use `h:commandButton' but the table logic is changed and it's not working properly. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You should look into the [PRG Pattern](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'h:commandLink' instead of `h:outputLink':

```
<h:commandLink id="lnkHidden" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" actionListener="#{bean.pageRedirect}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.sessionValue}" value="#{item.value}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: The advice given is good. But be sure that the links generated with this approach won't be crawlable. Check twice when using command links for plain get requests. Maybe you've chosen the wrong tool for your problem?  What's your functional requirement?